# Enlarge width of part in book while using \Large

Tags: fontsize, width, parts

About this code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{color}
\title{A book}
\author{PUCK}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\Large
\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Introduction}

\part[A part]{\Huge{\textcolor{red}{A part}}}

\chapter{A Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image: A part, too small]

I'd like that width of `\part[]{}`is bigger, and greater than section and chapter widths.
How could I do it?
Thank you

Comment: Please see the updated answer with larger page numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the package `titletoc` to format the part number and the page number.

[image: b]

(Using `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` to suppress **Contents** from the TOC)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % suppress Contents from toc
\usepackage{xcolor}
\title{A book}
\author{PUCK}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{titletoc}% added <<<<<  

\titlecontents{part}
[0pt]
{\addvspace{2pc}}
{}%
{\Huge\bfseries}
{\hspace{1em plus 1fill}\bfseries\Large\contentspage}
[\addvspace{0.5pc}]


\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    \Large
    \tableofcontents
    
    \newpage
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \part[\Huge A part]{{\textcolor{red}{A part}}} % changed <<<<
    
    \chapter{A Chapter}
    
\end{document}
```

To suppress the `0.1` from the first section  use

```
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
    \section*{Introduction}% non numbered section
```

[image: c]

To enlarge the part page number use

[image: x]

```
\titlecontents{part}
[0pt]  
{\addvspace{2pc}}
{}
{\Huge\bfseries}
{\hspace{1em plus 1fill}\bfseries\Huge\contentspage}% Huge page number<<<
[\addvspace{0.5pc}]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I'd like to have also the page number as Large as `I A part`. How Must I do? Thank you very much

Comment: @Puck I added the code at the end of the answer.